# Importing tables in Mathematica from web - empty cell problem

Tags: import, wolfram-mathematica

I use:
`data=Import["http://weburl/","Data"]`
to import data from one site. On that page there are tables. This creates nested lists, and you can easily get the data in table form. For example:
`Grid[data[[1]]]`
would give something like this:

```
Player Age Shots Goals
  P1    24    10    2 
  P2    22     5    0
  P3    28    11    1
  ...
```

Now, here is the problem. If one cell in the html table is empty, for example an entry for "Age", then in html this would look like this: `<td></td>`. Mathematica doesn't include take it in the list at all, not even as, for example, a "Null" value. Instead, this row would just be represented by a list of length 3 and data would be moved by one column, so you'd get "Shots" in place of "Age" and "Goals" in place of "Shots" and "Goals" would be empty.
For example, a "P4" whos age is unknown (empty cell in html table), who had 10 shots and scored 0 goals would be imported as list of length 3 not 4 and moved by one:

```
Player Age Shots Goals
  P1    24    10    2 
  P2    22     5    0
  P3    10     0  
  ...
```

This poses a difficult problem, because if you have a few empty fields then you can't tell from the list to which column it belongs. Is there a way to put a "Null" on an empty cell in html tables when importing in Mathematica? For example, P4 element in list would look like this:
`data[[1,5]]`
`{"P4","Null",10,0}`
instead of: 
`{"P4",10,0}`

Comment: In belisarius' words: Allow me to welcome you to StackOverflow and remind three things we usually do here: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too answering questions in your area of expertise 2) Read the FAQs 3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by using the gray triangles, as the credibility of the system is based on the reputation that users gain by sharing their knowledge. Also remember to accept the answer that better solves your problem, if any, by pressing the checkmark sign

Comment: It would be helpful to provide an example page to test with.

Comment: In the end I used Import["url", "FullData"]//InputForm, which gave me the desired result. But I will definitely have in mind all you suggestion for my future work. //InputForm was very helpful command. Thank you all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As lumeng points out, you can use `FullData` to get the HTML table element to fill out properly.  Here's a simpler illustration of this.

```
in = ImportString["\<<html><table>
   <tr>
   <td>(1,1)</td>
   <td>(1,2)</td>
   <td>(1,3)</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>(2,1)</td>
   <td></td>
   <td>(2,3)</td>
   </tr>
   </table></html>\>",
   {"HTML", "FullData"}];
Grid[in[[1, 1]]]
```

If you want more complete control of the output, I'd suggest that you `Import` the page as XML.  Here's an example.

```
in = ImportString["\<<html><table>
    <tr>
    <td>(1,1)</td>
    <td>(1,2)</td>
    <td>(1,3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>(2,1)</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>(2,3)</td>
    </tr>
    </table></html>\>", "XML"];
Column[Last /@ Cases[in,
   XMLElement["td", ___], Infinity]]
```

You'll need to read up a bit on XML in general and Mathematica's version, namely the `XMLObject`.  It's a delight to work with, once you get the hang of it, though.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `"\<...\>"` syntax that you use in the example string?

Comment: @WReach. This form properly recognizes newline characters so it is commonly used when entering a block of text.

Comment: OK the {"Html","FullData"} does the job, I get all the information. But I'll have to take another approach, "FullData" totally destroys the well structured data I get with "Data". Since on my page there is a huge number of tables that change, these nested lists are just too much of a mess. So I'll probably try to replace <td></td>s and similar empty cells replace with <td>Null</td> and then import with "Data".

Comment: In the end I used Import["url", "FullData"]//InputForm, which gave me the desired result.
But I will definitely have in mind all you suggestion for my future work.
//InputForm was very helpful command.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

```
In[13]:= htmlcode = "<html><table border=\"1\">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td></td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
</tr>
</table><html>";

In[14]:= file = ToFileName[{$TemporaryDirectory}, "tmp.html"]
Out[14]= "/tmp/tmp.html"


In[15]:= OpenWrite[file]
WriteString[file,htmlcode]
Close[file]
FilePrint[file]
Out[15]= OutputStream[/tmp/tmp.html,18]
Out[17]= /tmp/tmp.html
During evaluation of In[15]:=
<html><table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
<td>row 1, cell 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td></td>
<td>row 2, cell 3</td>
</tr>
</table><html>
In[23]:= Import[file,"Elements"]//InputForm
Out[23]//InputForm=
{"Data", "FullData", "Hyperlinks", "ImageLinks", "Images", "Plaintext", "Source", "Title", "XMLObject"}
In[22]:= Import[file,"FullData"]//InputForm
Out[22]//InputForm=
{{{{"row 1, cell 1", "row 1, cell 2", "row 1, cell 3"}, {"row 2, cell 1", "", "row 2, cell 3"}}}, {}}
```

Comment: dev, what are you trying to accomplish here? Please explain what the code does.

Comment: @rcollyer as I see it, he writes an example html table to a file which he reads back with `Import`. The option "FullData" is used to fill in the blanks. Writing the file could have been done somewhat easier with 'Put' or 'Export'. It is even unnecessary to use a file for this demonstration as there is also `ImportString` which treats a string as a file to import from.

Comment: @Sjoerd, I know what it does, but I'm trying to encourage a "more explanation, less code" type of approach. In my mind, a big block of code is essentially useless with out any accompanying explanation.  In its current form, it serves the purpose of answering the question, but only in the broadest sense because it does not provide any guidance as to the context or motivation of the solution. Its like reading a math proof without any accompanying text; it may be correct, but it barely qualifies as readable.

Comment: As I said on Mark McClures post I'll try to give value "Null" to empty cells since FullData destroys the elegance of "Data".
So I'll import the html code, put Null to empty cells and them ImportString[data, "Data"] and should get an easy readable table.

Answer (score 3):

Using Computist's sample, you could also do:

```
htmlcode = "<html><table border=\"1\">
  <tr>
  <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
  <td>row 1, cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>row 2, cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  </table><html>";

StringReplace[htmlcode, "<td></td>" -> "<td>###</td>"];

ImportString[%, "Data"] /. "###" -> Null
```